# Passing dataframe as argument to function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments

I am writing a function to process data from a huge dataframe (row by row) which always has the same column names. So I want to pass the dataframe itself as a function to read out the information I need from the individual rows. However, when I try to use it as argument I can't read the information from it for some reason.

Dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame("Name" = c("A","B"), "SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c("21,34,456,567,23,123,34", "15,345,567,3,23,45,67,76,34,34,55,67,78,3"))
```

My code:

```
List <- do.call(list, Map(function(DT) {
  DT <- as.data.frame(DT)
  aa <- as.numeric(strsplit(DT$Age, ","))
  mean.aa <- mean(aa)
},
DF))
```

Trying this I get a list with the column names, but all Values are NULL.

Expected output : 
My expected output is a list with length equal to the number of rows in the data frame. Under each list index there should be another list with the age of the corresponding row (an also other stuff from the same row of the data table, later).

```
DF <- apply(data.frame("Name" = c("A","B"), "SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c("21,34,456,567,23,123,34", "15,345,567,3,23,45,67,76,34,34,55,67,78,3"), "mean.aa" = c(179.7143, 100.8571)), 1, as.list)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is a list with length equal to the number of rows in the data frame. Under each list index there should be another list with the age of the corresponding row (an also other stuff from the same row of the data table, later)

Comment: If you want a list of 1 row dataframes : `split(DF,seq(nrow(DF))`, but please provide the exact expected output, it will be much easier to help.

Comment: Can you show us the output that matches your example?

Comment: What about `apply(DF, 1, as.list)` ?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Why don't you use the code applied to your expected output ?

Comment: in my expected output I calculated the mean before and just wrote in in there. also I want to add many other calculations later. For that I need to be able to access the values in the individual rows in the function

Comment: `lapply(split(DF, seq(nrow(DF))), function(i)split.default(i, names(i)))` almost gets you there but I suspect that what you need can be done in a simpler way

Comment: thank you, but with this code I would only transform my data frame into a list right? but I am looking for a way to make calculations inside the function (e.g. calculating the mean as in the example)

Comment: So why not do something like `library(tidyverse); DF %>% separate_rows(Age)  %>% mutate(Age = as.numeric(Age)) %>% group_by(Name, SN) %>% summarise(mean_age = mean(Age), var_age = sd(Age))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
DF <- data.frame("Name" = c("A","B"), "SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c("21,34,456,567,23,123,34", "15,345,567,3,23,45,67,76,34,34,55,67,78,3"))

apply(DF, 1, function(row){
  aa <- as.numeric(strsplit(row["Age"], ",")[[1]])
  row["mean.aa"] <- mean(aa)
  as.list(row)
})
```

Comment: what if one of the results calculated in the function would be a list. Is it possible to have it also in my result list with the other results?

Comment: ah got it: `list(as.list(row), otherList)`